# Send android device to sleep mode

Tags: android

I want to test my app when the device is in sleep mode.

Screen off is not a good sign because the device may be on because of other things. I want to be sure that device is in sleep mode. Is there any command via ADB or other thing to send the device in sleep mode explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

According to this other thread (and I just checked):
[How to lock Android screen via ADB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850192/how-to-lock-android-screen-via-adb)

```
adb shell input keyevent 26
```

Does the trick! Good stuff.

Answer (score -2):

may be this will help you.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
     wl.acquire();
       ..screen will stay on during this section..
     wl.release();
```

[more details are here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Comment: This code acquire the wake lock so it wake up, I want to force the device to goes to sleep.